# Get pathname from window and store it in state to use in fetch function

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function:

```
  fetchData = () => {
      fetch('/api/customerNodes' + this.state.number)
          .then(response => response.text())
          .then(message => {
              this.setState({responseText: message});
          });
    };
```

If I point my browser to `localhost:3000/1234` and I want to get the pathname of 1234, I do something like this. `const num = window.location.pathname;`

The problem I face is im not able to set that value to state.

```
  componentDidMount() {
    const num = window.location.pathname;
    this.setState({ number: num });
    console.log(this.state.number);
    //setInterval(this.fetchData, 250);
  }
```

The `console.log` is empty.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `setState` is asynchronous and you can't expect it to execute before the next line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the callback function in `this.setState`

```
const num = window.location.pathname;

this.setState({ number: num }, () => {
  console.log(this.state.number, 'number');
});
```

setState() is usually asynchronous, which means that at the time you console.log the state, it's not updated yet.By putting the log in the callback of the setState() method it is executed after the state change is complete.

Comment: Thank you so much. This helped. I called the fetchData function within the call back.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous and you can't expect it to execute before the next line of code.
 From the docs:

> React may batch multiple setState() calls into a single update for performance.

Comment: a solution would be great in addition to this explaination.

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is async method. If you log state in `render` method, you can get the number.

Comment: im not worried about logging. im worried about using. i need that number to fetch an api